# where does YouTube downloads for offline use get saved to?

Tags: youtube

After I download them, they suddenly disappear and I have to download them again. When they disappear, the "downloads" menu in the side bar disappears.

Where does YouTube those videos for offline use in local device? I am on Mac.

Comment: Safari? or another app? Usually all apps you define the "save to" location. Have you checked in preferences?

Answer (score 0):

From [this site](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/in-what-folder-can-youtube-premium-downloaded-videos-be-found.2354694/), it seems as if there is no possible way to download YouTube videos via YouTube Premium on Mac computers.

From what I can see from these users, it seems like the video does not download locally regardless, sadly.

1. *"YouTube Premium video downloads are only available on mobile devices such as iPhone and/or iPad. They apparently will not download on a Mac."*
2. *"Strange, there was a progress circle showing a download process, though it was on the website itself and not in the usual downloads progress area at bottom of Chrome."*
3. *"That progress circle means that it will be downloaded in your devices. It will not download like a file, its only for offline watch into the YouTube app."*